# Is Russia notified before prominent visits to Kyiv?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations, armed-conflict, ukraine

There has been several prominent visits to Kyiv since the war started, including U.S. Secretary of State Antony Blinken, US Defense Secretary Lloyd Austin, UK prime minister Boris Johnson, and United Nations Secretary-General Antonio Guterres. Is Russia notified before these visits so they can avoid accidentally triggering a "Pearl Harbor moment", or is it kept a secret? What is regarded as safest, to tell them or not to tell them?

Comment: I would say it is unlikely as I have heard reports that there is fears of them setting up false flag operations and there could be fear of them doing it with a leader and trying to blame Ukraine.

Comment: So far it was safe for all foreign visitors. But they probably think twice before going.

Comment: @JoeW I think a false flag in an active war zone is an oxymoron. Every diplomat that visits Ukraine understands the risks that they can be collateral damage, especially if the enemy doesn't know they are there.

Comment: @uberhaxed I disagree, false flags in a war zone can be critical to propaganda when an attack happens and one side blames the other side in order to get outrage at them.

Comment: @JoeW That's kind of irrelevant once the parties are already at war. The difference between this and a pearl harbor situation is that the US was not in the second world war and had no intention of entering the second world war (at least on paper). That was necessary to explain to the public a reversal of the prior policy of "stay out of European wars".

Comment: @uberhaxed No it is not when you consider war crimes or other acts that could draw in 3rd parties to the conflict. If Russia was to try and set up the deaths of ambassadors/leaders/prominent figures as being caused by Ukraine or people related to them it could have a large impact on support for Ukraine.

Comment: @JoeW war crimes are not relevant here. Civilians killed by collateral damage is allowed by the Geneva conventions if there is anticipated military gain. The Geneva conventions also only allows neutral parties to claim third party status. A party supplying military aid is not a neutral party by definition. There is literally nothing in the Geneva conventions that will protect European or American diplomats in an active war zone such as in Ukrainian cities. I would also advise you not use the word "war crime" unless there are actual war crimes as that is getting as diluted as the word "nazi".

Comment: A false flag is also an oxymoron when the victims are perfectly aware who did what.  If say Boris Johnson had been killed walking around in Kiev the UK government would be perfectly clear on who had been responsible and the game would only be worthwhile to convince Russian and neutral countries that Russia had nothing to do with it.  Since the whole point would be to avoid mistakenly escalating by killing foreign dignitaries there is no loss telling the Russians *exactly* what is going on.

Comment: @uberhaxed They are relevant as a possible false flag operation which is what you are objecting to. The point of a false flag operation is to try and make the other side look bad so that they lose international support. If Russia can assassinate a high value target and blame it on Ukraine it could impact the support they are getting. The point being that the fear might be Russia could target someone and attempt to blame it on Ukraine. And I have never said anything anything about neutral parties, just 3rd parties who are not Russia or Ukraine.

Comment: @JoeW You don't need to assassinate someone in a war zone. You can just run a military operation and kill them and claim they were collateral damage and have plausible deniability (especially if the attacking party was not officially aware that they were there). I'm really not seeing what you don't understand about "war zone". Not letting Russia know that foreign diplomats are there gives them cover and allows them to claim whatever they want.

Comment: @uberhaxed Either way knowing when a person is coming makes it easier to run any sort of operation in order to achieve that goal.  And letting Russia know who is coming and when could be used to make that person a target. All I have been saying is that Russia could use information like that to target the people who are visiting which could be a reason they don't inform Russia.

Comment: Putin has been calling the Ukraine war a false flag since the beginning. No one outside Russia actually believes them, but it has been reasonably effective among the Russian poulation, so there's no internal rebellion.

Answer (score 14):

If I recall the timing correctly, most of these visits you mentioned were announced to the public before they happened. You could read in western newspapers that these visits were going to happen usually a day or two before the politicians travelled. So they are definitely not secret and one would expect the Russian government to be aware of all information that is publicly available and relevant to them. I don't know whether the Russian government is informed separately but I don't think that would be necessary.

Comment: The Boris Johnson visit [was a secre](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/apr/10/johnsons-trip-to-kyiv-was-planned-in-secret-blindsiding-the-worlds-media)t to basically everyone until he actually arrived in Ukraine, doubt the others were though.

Comment: Bulgarian prime minister Petkov announced his recent visit almost a week in advance.

Comment: According to abcnews the visit by Antony Blinken and Lloyd Austin was a secret "--until Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelenskyy spilled just hours after they were wheels up. " Source: https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/inside-blinken-austins-risky-secret-visit-ukraine/story?id=84295558